# Compare time series with different sizes

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance

I have two time series $T_{1}, T_{2}, ..., T_{K}$ and $D_{1}, D_{2}, ..., D_{M}$ with $K>M$. Is there a way to compare those two time series, i.e. if the small time series $D$ preserves the trends of the larger time series $T$?

Comment: [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) may be helpful.